# Weka Experiment with API "ExpType"

Tags: java, api, weka

I am quite new with JavaCode and I try to use it to conduct experiments on Weka. I try to use this code: https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/files/ExperimentDemo.java given by Weka.

However, I don´t know how to set Experiment Type on this code.

```
// 1. setup the experiment
System.out.println("Setting up...");
Experiment exp = new Experiment();
exp.setPropertyArray(new Classifier[0]);
exp.setUsePropertyIterator(true);

String option;

// classification or regression
option = Utils.getOption("exptype", args);
if (option.length() == 0)
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("No experiment type provided!");

SplitEvaluator se = new weka.experiment.ClassifierSplitEvaluator ();   //my
Classifier sec    = null;
```

"I could not find how to set "exptype" on API. What should be written there for "classification".

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the Javadoc of the `main` method:

```java
  /**
   * Expects the following parameters: 
   * <ul>
   *   <li>-classifier "classifier incl. parameters"</li>
   *   <li>-exptype "classification|regression"</li>
   *   <li>-splittype "crossvalidation|randomsplit"</li>
   *   <li>-runs "# of runs"</li>
   *   <li>-folds "# of cross-validation folds"</li>
   *   <li>-percentage "percentage for randomsplit"</li>
   *   <li>-result "arff file for storing the results"</li>
   *   <li>-t "dataset" (can be supplied multiple times)</li>
   * </ul>
   * 
   * @param args    the commandline arguments
   * @throws Exception  if something goes wrong
   */
```

These are the parameters (as `java.lang.String` array) that you have to supply when executing the main method. This example class is designed to be called from the command-line with parameters.

Here is an example for a command-line:

```
java -cp weka.jar:. ExperimentDemo -classifier "weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -M 2" -exptype classification -splittype crossvalidation -runs 10 -folds 10 -result results.arff -t dataset.arff
```

**NB:** This command assumes Linux (use `;` as path separator under Windows) and that the `weka.jar` file, the class file of the aforementioned example class and the dataset `dataset.arff` are all in the current directory.

Or if you want to call the `main` method yourself, construct a `String` array accordingly:

```java
String[] options = new String[]{
  "-classifier",
  "weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -M 2",
  "-exptype",
  "classification",
  "-splittype",
  "crossvalidation",
  "-runs",
  "10",
  "-folds",
  "10",
  "-result",
  "results.arff",
  "-t",
  "dataset.arff"
};
```

Comment: Thank you this works great on Eclipse. Do you mind if I also ask how to give several classifiers as input ? In this code I can only give 1 classifier although I can compare performance of this classifier on several datasets. So at the end, my aim is to have a matrix with the comparison of several classifiers and several datasets together.

Comment: If you look at the code again, where the classifier is being set, you can see that the classifier is added as an array (`exp.setPropertyArray(new Classifier[]{c}); `). As the name of the class suggests, it shows you how to use the Experiment API (which is not trivial). Just pull out the relevant code bits and create your own experiment that way.